# "Incompatible Address" creating BluetoothListener

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

I'm trying to use Bluetooth on Windows 7. It's a Dell laptop with integrated bluetooth and the Dell drivers, and I'm using the 32feet library in a C# project in VS2012.

I've simplified things to this function, called at program start;

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        Guid service = new Guid("{7A51FDC2-FDDF-4c9b-AFFC-98BCD91BF93B}");
        BluetoothListener bl = new BluetoothListener(service);
        bl.Start();
        BluetoothClient bc = bl.AcceptBluetoothClient();

    }
```

When I create the listener, I get the error "An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used."

The stack trace downstream from this call is;

```
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)   
  at InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.WindowsBluetoothListener.CreateSocket()
  at InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.WindowsBluetoothListener.Construct(Guid service)
  at InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothListener..ctor(BluetoothFactory factory, Guid service)
  at InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothListener..ctor(Guid service)
```

The `BluetoothRadio.IsSupported` property returns `TRUE`.

I've done a bit of Googling around and not found very much of relevance. Can anyone suggest where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a fair chunk of time on this, and trying to get the commercial alternative [Wireless Communication Library](http://www.btframework.com/) to work I went back to basics and tried using Bluetooth to stream audio from my phone, use a Bluetooth mouse etc- previously I'd confirmed I could see devices and pair with them and assumed this meant all was well but hadn't had a need to actually *use* those devices.

Turned out that although detection and pairing worked, nothing else did. Tried another Windows 7 machine and the devices did work. Tried reinstalling drivers, the only thing that actually solved it was to get a new HD (since I didn't want to trash my system if it proved unnecessary) and do a fresh install of Windows 7.

So I don't know the root cause, but if anyone else finds this for the same reason it may save a few days :)